# Selecting attributes with query in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects

I have a Street_Light shapefile. It contains a field **(POLE_TYPE)**.

POLE_TYPE can only have two values: **"concrete"** or **"iron"**

I am trying to select **POLE_TYPE=iron**.

When I tried manually by selecting by attributes, it showed 454 features but when my code run it selects only one feature.

Where did I go wrong?

Here is my code:

```c#
ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument mxd = ArcMap.Application.Document as ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMap map = mxd.FocusMap;
for (int i = 0; i < map.LayerCount; i++)
{
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ILayer lay = map.Layer[i];
    if (map.Layer[i].Name == "Street_Light")
    {
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer flay = lay as ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer;
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureSelection fsel = flay as ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureSelection;

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IQueryFilter qfltr = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.QueryFilterClass();
        qfltr.WhereClause = "POLE_TYPE ='IRON'";
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureCursor cur = flay.Search(qfltr, true);
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeature fea = cur.NextFeature();
        while (fea != null)
        {              
            fsel.SelectFeatures(qfltr, ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.esriSelectionResultEnum.esriSelectionResultAdd, true);
            fea = cur.NextFeature();
        }    
        mxd.ActiveView.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last parameter for [`IFeatureSelection.SelectFeatures`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IFeatureSelection_SelectFeatures.htm), `justone`, indicated if you want to select just one (true) or all (false) features that satisfy the query filter. You would need to set it to false

```
fsel.SelectFeatures(qfltr, ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.esriSelectionResultEnum.esriSelectionResultAdd, false);
```

Also, since you are not adding selected features one by one but rather using the query filter, you can remove the loop  `while (fea != null)` and associated cursor.